# Spring restful @ExceptionHandler has too high priority/order

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I have an `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method in a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class.

This method must catch all exceptions, but *after* some default handlers have handled some exceptions, not as *first* handler (for example, it should not handle `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException`, otherwise the forwarding to the login page, which is done by Spring, does not work anymore).

I've found a lot of stuff but either old (not using `@ControllerAdvice`) or with Interfaces that cannot be used, because *both* html and JSON must fit to the return type of the method signature (using the class `ResponseEntity`, not some ModelAndView or String).

My current exception handler test method, which works fine:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleExceptions(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    //sort MIME types from accept header field
    String accept = request.getHeader("accept");
    if(accept != null) {
        String[] mimes = accept.split(",");
        //sort most quality first
        Arrays.sort(mimes, new MimeQualityComparator());
        //if json, return as json
        String firstMime = mimes[0].split(";")[0];
        if (firstMime.equals("application/json")) {
            ExceptionWrapper exceptionVO = new ExceptionWrapper(ex);
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionWrapper>(exceptionVO, headers, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    //if not json, return as html
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    String error = "<h1>Internal Server Error 500</h1><br>";
    error += "Please copy the following text and send it to your server admin:<br><br>";
    error += "<pre>" + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex) + "</pre>";
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(error, headers, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

It basically just decides in which format to return the error.

How can i lower the priority of this exception handler while *still maintaining* the Spring default exception handlers? Do i need to add some fancy Java-Config?

---

I already tried to create a class which implements `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and have overridden the `handleExceptionInternal` method there, which did not work. Spring complained it could not find a `HttpStatus` object to pass into the overridden method (ive tried providing that as bean, too).

I also tried using `@Order` on my `@ControllerAdvice` which changed nothing.

*Spring Version 4.0.9*